# Text overflow in a TextButton Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I wrap the text inside the button, I have used the overflow method in the text widget but it doesn't work. The output I got is this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _awaitValueBottomDrawer(context);
      },
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        fixedSize: const Size(200, 120),
        primary: Colors.white,
        textStyle:TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Your Starting Location',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              Text(address,overflow: TextOverflow.fade)
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Colors.white,),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

please help

Comment: Try to wrap the `Text(address,overflow: TextOverflow.fade)` inside a sizedbox and give a width. Then, it should work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `Column` widget with `Expanded` to handle text overflow error set with maxLines property value `1`

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _awaitValueBottomDrawer(context);
        },
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            fixedSize: const Size(200, 120),
            textStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const [
                Text(
                  'Your Starting Location',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
                Text(
                  address,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                  // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
                  maxLines: 1,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Ouput:** with `TextOverflow.fade`

[image: //]

**Ouput:** with `TextOverflow.ellipsis`

[image: //]

Comment: Thank you very much, this one worked as well. Appreciate it :)